# Q-factor in a laser cavity and second derivative

Tags: optics, laser, laser-cavity

I found the following text regarding laser cavities. But I do not understand why they use the second derivate instead of the first. Since the second can take any positive or negative value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The second derivative of a function is an indicator of "flatness", because it is the rate of change of the gradient (the rate of change of the rate of change).  A flat peak has a very small changing gradient, and hence has a small second derivative.  In contrast a very sharp peak has a very fast changing gradient, so has a large second derivative.

In the context of this $Q$-factor, a flat curve gives a small value of $|\omega_2|$ and hence a large value of $Q$, according to this definition.  The fact that $\omega_2$ could be positive or negative seems irrelevant here, as we're taking the absolute value.